# How can I verify if compression is working correctly in Kafka 0.8.2.2?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using Kafka 0.8.2.2 and am trying to set up compression. I am providing the compression-codec (gzip) as an argument to the console producer like below.

./kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:171 --compression-codec gzip --topic testTopic

Questions
Is this the only place where I need to specify compression? 
How do I verify if compression is indeed taking place?
How do I quantify the benefit I am getting from compression?
What files (.index, .log) I should look for and compare the sizes with and without compression to estimate the benefit?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

How to verify if compression is happening?

Use `DumpLogSegments` tool and substitute your dir location / log file name (default `log.dir` is `/tmp/kafka-logs`)

```sh
bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.DumpLogSegments --files /your_kafka_logs_dir/your_topic-your_partition/00000000000000000000.log --print-data-log | grep compresscodec
```

You will see something like below:

```
baseOffset: 0 lastOffset: 0 count: 1 ... compresscodec: NONE ...
baseOffset: 1 lastOffset: 1 count: 1 ... compresscodec: GZIP ...
baseOffset: 2 lastOffset: 2 count: 1 ... compresscodec: SNAPPY ...
baseOffset: 3 lastOffset: 3 count: 1 ... compresscodec: LZ4 ...
```

More info can be found in documentation here https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#design_compression

Comment: Thanks, i could verify

Comment: When running this with `--print-data-log` the output also print the records. I've replaced that flag with `--verify-index-only` to only print the metadata. Here is your example with this different flag `bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.DumpLogSegments --files /your_kafka_logs_dir/your_topic-your_partition/00000000000000000000.log --verify-index-only | grep compresscodec`

Comment: @marina How is this done with Confluent Cloud?

Comment: @Marina this can be done on AWS MSK brokers?