# Kafka message compression not working as expected

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

My project uses Apache Kafka for sending messages. Over the period of time, payload becomes heavy and has crossed the default size of 1MB. We thought of compressing the message at Producer end, but it is not working as expected.

Here is the producer config,

```
spring:
    kafka:
        consumer:
          group-id: group_name
          bootstrap-servers: broker-server:9343
        producer:
          bootstrap-servers: ${spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers}
          key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
          value-serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
          compression-type: gzip
```

but with above configuration, if I send a message more than 1 MB, I am facing below error,

> org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Send failed; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordTooLargeException: The message is 1909152 bytes when serialized which is larger than 1048576, which is the value of the max.request.size configuration

Is there any other configuration required to enable compression ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The configuration `max-request-size` will help you in this case. This configuration is used to specify the maximum size of a request. By default, It is set to 1MB, that why you are seeing the error.
You can add the following property in your property file:

```
spring:
  kafka:
   producer:
     max-request-size: 2097152
```

Note 2MB = 2097152 bytes (you can change it according to your requirement).

Comment: Thanks for your time. How can I check if message is really compressed ?

Comment: You can refer to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36590471/how-can-i-verify-if-compression-is-working-correctly-in-kafka-0-8-2-2. I Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks. If compression is handled using compression-type property, then why we need max request size property? If the message size is more than 1 MB then compression method should compress and make the size less and send it to Kafka ? Why we need to specify the size property also ?